# Remove overlapping axis labels in orthographic view

Tags: plotting

I tried:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  ParametricPlot3D[{t, t^2, t^3}, {t, -2, 2},
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
   BoxRatios -> 1/GoldenRatio,
   ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{t, t^2, t^3}, {t, -2, 2},
   AxesLabel -> {"x", None, "z"},
   BoxRatios -> 1/GoldenRatio,
   ViewPoint -> {0, Infinity, 0}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{t, t^2, t^3}, {t, -2, 2},
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
   BoxRatios -> 1/GoldenRatio,
   ViewPoint -> {Infinity, 0, 0}]
  }, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

In the second image, I got rid of the axis label using None, but note in the lower right corner I think I have two zeros interfering with one another. Any easy way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: You can specify which axes will show up with the option `Axes` so for the first image try `ParametricPlot3D[...,Axes->{True,True,False}]` , for the second use `Axes->{True,False,True}`, and the third should be obvious.

Comment: Perfecto! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @N.J.Evans and David: I would like to encourage NJ to post his solution proposed in the comment as an answer, so that David can properly accept it, and the question will show up as answered. See [this post by Ian](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/27951) in MMA.Meta regarding this very situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Mathematica shows all axes by default, which is not ideal for an orthographic projection. You can specify which axes will show up with the option Axes psecifying `True` or `False` for each of {x,y,z}. For the first image try ParametricPlot3D[...,Axes->{True,True,False}] , for the second use Axes->{True,False,True}, and the third should be obvious.